# How to find last inserted id, when using laravel firstOrNew new method to inser the data

Tags: php, laravel-5

Am using laravel firstOrNew method to  insert the  data . when data is not present in the table it will insert the data. after inserting the data am unable to get the last inserted id.

ex:

```
   $user = User::firstOrNew(['id'=>1]);
   $user->name='prasanna';
   $user->save();
   dd($user->id); //it prints true,  here i need last inserted  id
```

Comment: Try out `$user->lastInsertId()`

Comment: share exact code if any changed from given. this should work `dd($user->id);`

Comment: Try with id=> 3, i.e. something else than 1 . Pls also share users table definition.....

Answer (score 1):

Use `firstOrCreate` instead `firstOrNew`

`firstOrNew` is not persisted until `save()`  is not called, so it will not return `$user->id` here.

`firstOrNew` returns

```
return new static($attributes);
```

And `firstOrCreate` returns

```
return static::create($attributes);
```

Read the [difference](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent#mass-assignment)